# Remove everything before a blank line using sed

Tags: linux, windows, bash, sed

Lets say I have a file which is something like this:

```
"Testing is important"

Nothing is impossible
```

The output should be:

```
Nothing is impossible
```

This means the sed removed everything before new line. Also, I need to make sure it works on bash on windows.

Please help.

Comment: Do you want something like this: `sed '1,2d' file`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
sed '1,/^\s*$/d' file
```

\s is whitespace, it's same with

```
sed '1,/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Sed supports addressing lines both as numbers and as matching regex. In your case, you can delete all lines starting from 1, and ending with an empty line:

```
sed -e '1,/^$/d'
```

On Windows your files may contain contain carriage returns, in which case you can use:

```
sed -e '1,/^\r*$/d'
```

(assuming GNU sed)

Answer (score 0):

To allow for more than one blank line and multiple lines after the final blank line, you could use something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=""}{a=$0}END{print a}' file
```

This unsets the Record Separator `RS`, so that each block/paragraph is treated as a separate record. It assigns each record to the variable `a`, then prints the last value of `a` once the file has been processed. The Output Record Separator `ORS` is also unset, so that no newline is appended to the final block.